# Loading gif align in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a loading gif to be on the center of the page also in mobiles.
Have tried

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

but i had no luck.

```
#bw-preloader, #bw-preloader:after {

    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/ImksiyD.gif) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    border-radius: 0% !important;
    width: 256px !important;
    height: 256px !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin: -50px 0px 0px -50px; !important;
}

#bw-preloader {
border: 0px !important;
-webkit-transition: opacity 10s !important;

position: fixed !important;
top: 50% !important;
left: 50% !important;
margin: -50px 0px 0px -50px; !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
#bw-preloader {

position: fixed !important;
top: 50% !important;
left: 50% !important;
margin: -50px 0px 0px -50px; !important;
}
}
```

You can see it live  [here](http://www.tfeditor.com)

Could someone check it out if im missing something?

Also have tried

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your CSS as follows:

```
#bw-preloader, #bw-preloader:after {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ImksiyD.gif) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    border-radius: 0% !important;
    width: 256px !important;
    height: 256px !important;
    margin: -128px 0 0 -128px;
}
```

You need to adjust the top and right margins by half the height and width respectively.

Comment: What about the mobile version?? Your code is working perfect for large screens! Could you help me with the mobile?

Comment: @SteliosM. The idea should be similar if not identical for the mobile version. Make sure that the `margin` values are the same wherever you see `#bw-preloader` and that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This example code might help.

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container">
<p class="image-holder">
<img src="loading.gif" />
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.image-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff; 
    z-index: 999999;
    text-align: center;
}

.image-holder {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%; 
    top: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.image-holder img 
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    margin-top: -50%;   
}
```

**JS**

```
$('div.image-container').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: you are missing the negative margin for the .image-holder div
the code as is now is aligning the left upper corner of the div to the center

Comment: @flynorc Thanks! Fixed

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
position:absolute;
width:256px;
height:256px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin: -128px 0 0 -128px;
z-index:1000;
```

position absolute with the top:50% and left:50% move the elements left top part to the middle that is why you need to give it the negative margin of half the object witdht/height.
hope it helps